# Delete rows containing zero on all but a couple of worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro to delete rows containing a 0 value in column L on all but a few workbooks in my worksheet. I have found a macro that can do this on the activesheet and I tried to nest it in function that loops through the desired sheets but it still only delete's the zero's in the active sheet. Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
Sub nul_waarden_verwijderen()

 Dim WS As Worksheet
 Dim lngMyRow As Long
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "TB per 29122014" And WS.Name <> "SCOA" And WS.Name <> "105 Enterprise klad" And WS.Name <> "105 rekenblad" And WS.Name <> "list" Then         
            For lngMyRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
                If Val(Cells(lngMyRow, "L")) = 0 Then
                   Rows(lngMyRow).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next lngMyRow
        End If                                  
    Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have to add "WS" as qualifier in front of .Cells and .Rows

Comment: If you just write `Rows(<index>)` that's the same as writing `ActiveSheet.Rows(<index>)`. You need to tell the code which worksheet you want to work with by writing it as `WS.Rows(<index>)` within your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a qualifier in front of .Cells and .Rows in order for it to work on a specific worksheet. Without this qualifier, those two refer to ActiveSheet.Cells and ActiveSheet.Rows.

```
For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name <> "TB per 29122014" And WS.Name <> "SCOA" And WS.Name <> "105 Enterprise klad" And WS.Name <> "105 rekenblad" And WS.Name <> "list" Then
        For lngMyRow = WS.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If Val(WS.Cells(lngMyRow, "L")) = 0 Then
                WS.Rows(lngMyRow).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next lngMyRow
    End If
Next WS
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt expect it to be this simple, I was probably staring at my screen a bit to long ;)

Comment: It does work however a couple of values between 1 and -1 (eg 0,23) are also erased. I tried to change the 0 to 0.000 and "0.000" but that did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Get rid of 'Val'. Simply use 'If WS.Cells(lngMyRow, "L") = 0 Then...'